# How to get a specific value out of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get the `cp` value for which my `xerror`is the smallest. I fitted a model like below and printed the cptable. Since the list is so long, I displayed only the first 20 rows.

```
>printcp(RT_model)

 Regression tree:
rpart(formula = BW ~ ., data = train, method = "anova", 
control = rpart.control(minsplit = 0, minbucket = 1, cp = -1))

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] age      black    boy      cigar    collgrad hsgrad   married  
natal2   natal3   nosmoke  novisit  somecoll wtgain  

Root node error: 5.2267e+10/159689 = 327304

n= 159689 

               CP nsplit rel error  xerror      xstd
1      4.3760e-02      0   1.00000 1.00001 0.0054277
2      1.6392e-02      1   0.95624 0.95661 0.0050844
3      1.1851e-02      2   0.93985 0.94067 0.0049671
4      1.1133e-02      3   0.92800 0.92446 0.0049150
5      1.0735e-02      4   0.91686 0.91709 0.0048956
6      6.1850e-03      5   0.90613 0.90692 0.0048695
7      3.3414e-03      6   0.89994 0.90054 0.0048561
8      2.6481e-03      7   0.89660 0.89680 0.0048502
9      2.4185e-03      8   0.89395 0.89441 0.0048449
10     2.1499e-03      9   0.89154 0.89232 0.0048248
11     2.0960e-03     10   0.88939 0.88993 0.0048055
12     1.3600e-03     11   0.88729 0.88822 0.0048031
13     1.3513e-03     12   0.88593 0.88616 0.0047898
14     1.2209e-03     13   0.88458 0.88600 0.0047862
15     9.2359e-04     14   0.88336 0.88454 0.0047731
16     9.1119e-04     15   0.88243 0.88364 0.0047679
17     7.8948e-04     16   0.88152 0.88300 0.0047662
18     7.4059e-04     17   0.88073 0.88221 0.0047638
19     6.8623e-04     18   0.87999 0.88142 0.0047610
20     6.7196e-04     19   0.87931 0.88077 0.0047620
...
[ erreichte getOption("max.print") --  25545 Zeilen ausgelassen ]
```

Since there are so many values:

To get the `cp`with the smalles `xerror`, I use the following code:

```
   minCP <- RT_model$cptable[which.min(RT_model$cptable[,"xerror"]), "CP"]
```

The corresponding `xerror` of the `minCP` equals: `0.8690961 xerror`

Now I want to apply a rule called **"minimal xerror + standard deviation"**

The corresponding standard deviation of `minCP` equals `0.004700524 xstd`

I need the greatest value of the table that is equal or smaller than the new `xerror` called xerror_new (`0.8690961 xerror + 0.004700524 xstd = 0.8737966`). So I need the greatest value of the `xerror`column of the cptable which is less or equal to 0.8737966

How do I get the `cp`-value of the cptable which has an xerror smaller or equal to the `xerror_new`value of 0.8737966?

I tried the following but it failed hard.

```
  min_xerror <- RT_model$cptable[which.min(RT_model$cptable[,"xerror"]), 
  "xerror"]
```

this gave me the minimal `xerror`in the table. And the following gives me the corresponding minimal `xstd`

```
   min_xstd <- RT_model$cptable[which.min(RT_model$cptable[,"xerror"]), "xstd"]
```

here I apply the "minimal xerror + standard deviation" rule:

```
  xerror_new <- min_xerror + min_xstd
```

up to here I get values and everything is fine. From here I struggle:

```
  xerror_plus_xstd <- RT_model$cptable[which.max(RT_model$cptable["xerror"<= 
  min_xerror_xstd] & RT_model$cptable["xerror" >= min_xerror]), "xerror"]
```

or I tried this:

```
 xerror_plus_xstd <- RT_model$cptable[which.max(RT_model$cptable["xerror"<= min_xerror_xstd]), "xerror"]
```

Both yield no result.

How can I get this value? Thanks.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: My suggestion is that you use the `broomstick` package to convert the results into a data.frame and use `dplyr` to carry out the selection. You also coud share a reproducible example, so someone can help more effectively.